# What is the influence of parentheses on array pointers?

Tags: c++

While writing a program I found out that the output of

```
(*array3)[i]
```

is different than

```
*array3[i]
```

I don't really understand why. Could somebody explain to me what is happening in the computer?

The first snippet does what I want, namely: indexing through the array. In the last snippet, first the indexing is done and later the dereferencing. How can I visualise that?

```
int *array3 = nullptr;

void add(int *array1, int n1, int *array2, int n2, int **array3, int &n3){
    n3 = std::max(n1,n2);
    *array3 = new int[n3];
```

n3 could be an arbitrary number

Image of the first case:

[image]

Comment: The compiler needs to either do the dereferencing first or the indexing first.  But which one?   https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence   It turns out that indexing happens before dereferencing - unless you use parenthesis.

Comment: @Nadine There is no `(*array3)[i]` or `*array3[i]` in the code you have shown, which still makes it difficult to answer your question definitively. I *assume* `(*array3)[i]` is being used in a loop after `new[]` to populate the newly allocated `int[]` array?

Comment: @RemyLebeau I'm sorry for being incomplete. Your assumption is correct! With your explaination I think I understand my problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `(*array3)[i]`, the `*` dereference operator is first applied to `array3`, and then the `[]` subscript operator is applied to the result.

In `*array3[i]`, this gets treated as `*(array3[i])` because the `[]` subscript operator has a [higher precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) than the `*` dereference operator. So, the `[]` subscript operator is first applied to `array3`, and then the `*` operator is applied to the result.

Now, what is different about these?  Well, first you have to understand that a statement `P[N]`, where `P` is a pointer to some type `T`, is effectively the same as `*(P+N)`, ie the address held by the pointer is incremented by `N` number of `T` elements (ie, the address is increased by `sizeof(T) * N` number of bytes), and then the resulting address is dereferenced.

Let's assume `array3` is an pointer to an `int[]` array (since you did not actually show the declaration of `array3`), ie:

```cpp
int array[5] = {...};
int (*array3)[5] = &array;
```

Then:

- `(*array3)[i]` is essentially `*((*array3)+i)`. `*array3` first dereferences `array3` to access the `int[]` array itself.  Referring to an array itself will *decay* into a pointer to the 1st element of the array.  So now we have an `int*` pointer to the 1st `int` element of the array, then `[i]` is applied to that pointer, incrementing it by `i` number of `int` elements, and then it is dereferenced to access the actual `int` element.
- `*array3[i]` is essentially `*(*(array3+i))`. The address held by `array3` is incremented by `i` number of `int[5]` elements, then the result is dereferenced to access an `int[5]` array (which decays into a pointer), then that pointer is *dereferenced again*.

**UPDATE:** in the code example you have now provided, `array3` is an `int**` pointer to an `int*` pointer to an `int[]` array (that is dynamically allocated with `new[]`).  That slightly changes what I said above, but not by much.

- `(*array3)[i]` is essentially `*((*array3)+i)`. `*array3` first dereferences `array3` to access the `int*` pointer to the array.  This is effectively a pointer to the 1st `int` element of the array, then `[i]` is applied to that pointer, incrementing it by `i` number of `int` elements, and then it is dereferenced to access the actual `int` element.
- `*array3[i]` is essentially `*(*(array3+i))`.  The address held by `array3` is incremented by `i` number of `int*` elements, then the result is dereferenced to access an `int*` pointer, then that pointer is *dereferenced again*.

Comment: I edited my post with an image. Thanks for your reply. Do you know how I could visualize the last snippet? As far as I know. array3 is a pointer, so it's a variable that contains the adress. In the case of (*array3)[i]. *array3 is the first element of the array and the i is the offset in that array. In the last snippet actually I don't understand what array3[i] does. Could you help me by telling me how to visualize it?

Comment: @Nadine please add the declaration of `array3` to your post

Answer (score 0):

There are two operators that you are using here: `*` and `[]`. So when the compiler sees `*array3[i]`, does it do `*` first or `[]` first? The answer is that the `[]` operator has higher operator precedence, so in the absence of additional parentheses, it will do the `[]` first, then the `*`. That is, it will parse it as

```
*(array3[i])
```

This is clearly different than

```
(*array3)[i]
```

which does the dereference first then the array access.

Answer (score 0):

Parentheses can be used to change the order of operations.

The difference is analogous to the difference between these operations:

```
(1 + 2) * 3  // 9

 1 + 2  * 3  // 7
```

---

> ```
> (*array3)[i]
>
> *array3[i]
> ```

In first, the subscript operator is applied to the result of the indirection operator; in second, indirection operator is applied to the result of the subscript operator.